# Plumbing Nightmare - What would cause this?

Tags: plumbing, basement, sewer, clog, soil

Awful Rental House Plumbing. We moved into a 1950's house (with cast iron plumbing) on August 17, 2023. My owner is claiming that all plumbing clogs are from us, because that they did not have before us. This includes 3 major backflushes of sewage [image: Sewage 2 days after movein] and slow movement in the drain (4 months). Strangely, in 2 recent storms, water leaked out of the walls of the basement (flooding finished basement) [image: Drain fills with rocks floods]and during the same time we saw these peculiar behaviors: soil backup into the basement toilet, rocks and soil [image: Rocks coming our of water drain that goes into main sewer]coming up from the basement floor drain, and bubbling in the washer sink.And soil into toilet [image: Soil in toilet] What is wrong with plumbing?[image: Floor Drain]

Comment: Asking the same question when your question is closed rather than editing your closed question is not polite behavior in this stack.

Comment: Sounds like the main line out to the sewer has collapsed. 1950s could be Orangeburg, but it doesn't really matter. That's gonna be a spendy fix. About 10K USD in my city.

Comment: @popham -- that's probably why the owner wants to blame the tenant.

Comment: @Pete, reminds of that scene from Tommy Boy: "What did you do!" There it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wpFrdevEhs.

Comment: Sorry about that :) 

The code inspectors only looked inside the house and couldn't find the "big white PVC pipe" Wow how he blames us for everything including a bubbling washer sink based on a "cheeto" in the sewer vent stack and the giant gurgling sounds in the bathtub after flushing toilet. We are not allowed to have a garbage disposal? so we use a mesh, so no big food chunks. It's not funny though when he want me to pay $2K for it (5 months in), even though plumber said a full inspection would be useful?

Comment: Looking down that vent sewer stack is sometimes milky looking when flow slows